# $\sum_{i<j} \sum \text{Cov} (X_i, X_j) = {n \choose 2} (\text{E}[X_iX_j] - \text{E}[X_i] \text{E}[X_j] )$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

Suppose $X_i$, for $i = 1,2,..,n$, are random variables. Is it true that $$\sum_{i<j} \sum \text{Cov} (X_i, X_j) = {n \choose 2} \left(\text{E}[X_iX_j] - \text{E}[X_i] \text{E}[X_j] \right)?$$

I think this formula is true after writing down the covariance matrix. How to interpret the ${n \choose 2}$ term?

Comment: Why are the $i,j$ lingering on the RHS?

Comment: @user10354138 $ \text{Cov} (X_i, X_j) = \text{E}[X_iX_j] - \text{E}[X_i] \text{E}[X_j] $ is a formula, isn't it?

Comment: The formula you've written for $Cov(X_i, X_j)$ is correct. We would expect to have a summation on the right hand side unless the covariance is constant for every $i \neq j$.

Comment: If $X_{i} and X_{j}$ be the vectors and you want to compute summation of upper main diagonal of covariance matrix. As you know, all of those entries of matrix are different, so writing ${n \choose 2} $ is meaningless and you must write double sigma : $\Sigma\Sigma_{i<j}$

Comment: For example if $n=3$ you must sum $Cov(X_{1},X_{2})$ ,$ Cov(X_{1},X_{3})$ and $Cov(X_{2},X_{3}) $, Is it right?

Comment: It is correct as long as distributions of $X_i$ and $(X_i,X_j)$ do not depend on $i,j$. The $\binom{n}{2}$ factor counts the number of terms under the sum $\sum_i\sum_j$ where $i<j$.

Comment: It is wrong or at least confusing to use $i,j$ as indices ranging over set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ on LHS and at the same time using them as fixed numbers on RHS. If $\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ is the same for every pair $i,j$ with $i<j$ then you better write ${n \choose 2} \left(\text{E}[X_1X_2] - \text{E}[X_1] \text{E}[X_2] \right)$ on RHS. Further on LHS you only need one sigma sign with $i<j$ under it. The second should be left out.